# video not playing completly after join operation

Tags: c#, winforms, video

This following is a code to join two videos. When I run the program it joins two videos and puts joined video in a folder. The joined video size is correct as it should be.

But when I play the video it plays the first part of the video in WMP but when i play the video in VLC it plays the second part of video.

```
public void JoiningVideo()
{
    string j = @"D:/test2";

    string outputpath = @"D:/test3/beforeEventab1.wmv";
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(j);
    FileStream fs;
    fs = new FileStream(outputpath, FileMode.Append);
    foreach (FileInfo fi in di.GetFiles(@"*.wmv"))
    {
        byte[] bytesource = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fi.FullName);
        fs.Write(bytesource, 0, bytesource.Length);
    }
    fs.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know that each video-file starts with something called "[header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Header_%28computing%29)" ?

This part of the file contains information about the length etc.
If you want to join to seperate video files, you have to merge the headers to a new one containing information about both (joined) parts and to make sure that both videos fit to each other. (*)
Otherwise the video is not a valid file.

Due to the differences of the decoders of WMP and VLC, one recognises the first and the other one recognises the second file.
You can be lucky of that the the programs even played this 'corrupt' file! ;)

Just ask a search engine about `merge wmv` for a solution that should work for you!

(*)
To merge two videos they need to have

- The same format (e.g. Resolution, Framerate, Bitrate)
  If this does not apply, at least one of them has to be converted to match the other video
- The videos have to be 'glued' together, it is not sufficient to append one's data to the other one.
  Each video starts with a header. This header has to be changed to comprise information about the new (joined) video.
  Also the raw image data cannot be simply appended. Every image is like a piece of a puzzle fitting to the next image in the video. The transition is like a new piece of a puzzle that has to be created. It may even be necessary to change/reorder the whole second file in order to get a working transition.

I am not a specialist, but at leas I can tell you, that this procedure is different for each type (MPEG, WMV, ..) of video. The best approach is to use an existing library for this purpose.

Comment: no i dont know about the header and how to merge the both can u made some changes in code i gave i will be thankful and it may solve my problem

Comment: No i cant. Merging two videos is much more complex as I stated above, sorry. I'll expand my answer, it is easier to write there.